# Differences between the method of closing a excel file

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I have been using some functions for a while, and now I'm actually wondering, what is the difference between them. I know, that `xlWorkbook.Close(0)` closes the file, `xlAppQuit();` quits the excel application, and `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);` cleans up - releases COM objects. But what does it mean in practice? I just can't imagine the differences. The first two make my excel process dissapear from the Task Manager (so how is closing a workbook different than quitting if they both kill the excel process?), the last one does not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember those classes you call are COM objects. COM uses reference counting. So each time you use one of them in the backgound it +1's.

To properly clean up you need to decrement that counter. That is done through releasing your reference (wb=null) and then calling Marshall.ReleaseComObject(...).

If you fail do do so you introduce a memory leak as those COM objects stick around until your application is closed.